# Google assistant unable to find my Google Action

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created a Google Action using Dialogflow and Google Actions Console. After I created my first alpha release, I was able to use it both in my Android Phone, with this phone connected. However, it no more works.

1. I have 4 of my email addresses added to the alpha testers list.
2. I tried clicking on try now button from inviting listing.
3. I clicked on send to device and clicked on the push notification google send.
4. I got a message "Sorry, I couldn't find that.".

However, in the action console, its says action is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue when I didn't use the App for a while. I went again to Google action console, chose the version and right clicked and clicked on 'Test this version'. Then it worked. May be it helps you as well. Try it out.

[image: Google action console - alpha version]

Comment: in same account(where we make action) its work but in tester account its not work

Comment: Has this problem been solved?? I have the same problem